# Firebase Root View Controller Not Found Warning

Tags: objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I got a strange warning from Firebase Analytics today. It is:

```
<Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031011] Root view controller not found
```

The methods I am using is basically deleting a post and then displaying a status bar notification to the user that the post is deleted. This is the method that is called when we want to delete a post.

```
HomeViewNetwork.deletePost(postBlock: self.postDataBlock, handler: {
   AlertManager.showStatusRed(title: "Post deleted!")
})
```

And my displaying status function is:

```
class func showStatusRed(title: String) {
    let statusMessage = MessageView.viewFromNib(layout: .StatusLine)
    var config = SwiftMessages.defaultConfig
    config.presentationContext = .window(windowLevel: UIWindowLevelStatusBar)
    statusMessage.configureContent(body: title)
    statusMessage.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.98, green:0.11, blue:0.35, alpha:1.00)
    setUpStatusView(messageView: statusMessage)
    statusSwiftMessages.show(config: config, view: statusMessage)
}
```

The warning goes away if I comment the AlertManager.showStatusRed method. Also I am using SwiftMessages as my library for displaying the status bar notification.

I am not sure why Firebase is giving me this warning when Xcode is not giving any issues about root view controller. Any help is appreciated.

Related question for objective-C only project complied with Xcode 9 GM using FirebaseCore 4.0.4 (podfile.lock): [Xcode 9 <Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031011] Root view controller not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332454/xcode-9-warning-firebase-analyticsi-acs031011-root-view-controller-not-fou)

Comment: try checking configurations for SwiftMessage Library you had used here

Comment: I did try, but cannot find the reason why this happened. Also have no idea why Firebase would warn me about this when Xcode doesn't.

Comment: same issue here. Did you find a way out?

Comment: Nope, I haven't figured it out yet

Comment: Got this problem happening in iMessage for every screen that I present.  Analytics is not working as a result.

Comment: It probably has something to do with SwiftMessages showing your message in a new window. Try showing the message in the main window for comparison. If you can attach a sample project (or at least post details of your Firebase configuration), I'll take a look. (SwiftMessages author here.)

Answer (score 0):

Updating the firebase and other related dependencies to latest version fixed the issue on my project.

```
 - Firebase/Core (4.2.0):
 - FirebaseAnalytics (= 4.0.3)
 - FirebaseCore (= 4.0.7)
```

Answer on other thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46333312/342794