# Xcode 9 <Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031011] Root view controller not found

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-analytics, xcode9

Noticed following warning repeated multiple times on console when compiling project with Xcode 9.

```
Appname [33380] <Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031011] Root view controller not found
```

Other relevant details:

```
Appname [33380] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.40002000 started
Appname [33380] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see --shortened url--)
Appname [33380] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS003007] Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
Appname [33380] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
```

These repeated warnings " [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031011] Root view controller not found" flood the console when debugging with breakpoints. After few step-overs the simulator stops responding to touch and keyboard events (requires restarting the debugging session).

Perhaps I need to update the firebase?

Podfile.lock:

```
  - Firebase/Core (4.0.4):
  - FirebaseAnalytics (= 4.0.2)
  - FirebaseCore (= 4.0.4)
  - Firebase/DynamicLinks (4.0.4):
  - FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.0):
```

Related swift specific question:
[Firebase Root View Controller Not Found Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356479/firebase-root-view-controller-not-found-warning)

Answer (score 0):

Updating the firebase and other related dependencies to latest version fixed the issue:

You may use this command to update specific pod:

`pod update Firebase/DynamicLinks`

or `carthage update ..` for carthage based integration and similar steps for submodules or direct source integration of Firebase.

Podfile.lock after the update should have updated entries for `Firebase/Core v4.2.0`, etc:

```
 - Firebase/Core (4.2.0):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 4.0.3)
    - FirebaseCore (= 4.0.7)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (4.0.3):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 4.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 2.0)
  - FirebaseDynamicLinks (2.1.0):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 4.0)
  - FirebaseInstanceID (2.0.3)
```