# Firebase notifications not working in iOS 11

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, notifications, ios11

I'm developing an app that uses Firebase push notifications. It worked well until I tried in iOS 11. Using an iphone with ios 11 the notifications don't arrive. Here's my code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
  didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
  fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)
  (UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
      //Manage notification
  }

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
   willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
     withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler{
    //Manage notification
}
```

Neither of the methods are called.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm having an issue on iOS 11 as well. I don't have an iOS 10 device to test on to confirm it is an OS issue but push was working now it isn't. I could receive notifications when calling the APNs server directly so there may be a firebase bug. I've reached out to support and let you know if I hear back.

Comment: Yeah it's probably caused by Firebase, maybe they will update soon.. Thanks for the answer @Jeremiah

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356479/firebase-root-view-controller-not-found-warning ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an issue with Firebase. It seems to be related to a recent update of theirs instead of iOS 11. They are working on a fix for it.

In the meantime if you add `pod 'FirebaseInstanceID', '2.0.0'` to your podfile it will fix it.

You can read more here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/327#issuecomment-332655731

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll keep it open anyway until we get the update from firebase, then I will give you the answer if you update it. This way we can keep the correct solution here.

Comment: Helped for me. But should be pod 'FirebaseInstanceID', '2.0.0'

Answer (score 2):

I got stuck like 3 hours and then 2 steps found on net helped me.

1. Try call firebase notification send externally like this - just replace ServerKey for your account serverkey and FCM_TOKEN for your app fcm token:

> ```
> curl -X "POST" "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send" \
>      -H "Authorization: key=ServerKey" \
>      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
>      -d $'{
>   "notification": {
>     "body": "Testing with direct FCM API",
>     "title": "Test Message",
>     "badge": "0",
>     "sound": "default"
>   },
>   "registration_ids": [
> "FCM_TOKEN"
>   ]
> }'
> ```

2. You will get some error response probably. I've got "InvalidApnsCredential" which was due to not matching TeamID in firebase and apple developer account (more specifically auth token key) -> also be careful that firebase really changes TeamID event after save (it gave me many invalid save changes which occured after browser refresh)

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`

```
 extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
            completionHandler(.alert)
        }
    }
```

and set it to `UNUserNotificationCenter` object inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
      return true
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me, notifications are fine in every other OS, except iOS 11

Comment: Notifications also aren't coming through when the app is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Check this in your project capability. It's helped me)
[image]

Comment: I already have that option on. I don't think it's about xcode but about firebase.

Comment: @JaimeAlcántaraArnela Hmm, it's working well for me now for iOS 10-11. Did you check this [example](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift)? I think the problem can be in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true
```

Comment: Sorry, my memories solution isn't really the solution. Message just arrived when app is active.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced with this issue. I followed all instructions bu still can not get the notifications in background.

When I archive and send build to test flight (and approved by apple) the problem is gone away. No I can send notifications.